# Hibernate Session null-pointer exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, oracle11g, tomcat7

I have been stuck with this issue for days cannot figure it out, I mean I know the sessionFactory must be null as the stacktrace indicates but I cannot understand why? The exception always comes back to the line:

```
Session session = hibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
```

Here is a trimmed version of the stacktrace:

```
DEBUG - Creating new transaction with name [com.sga.app.dao.DisplayStatsDAO$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f03b1e71.getForename]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
DEBUG - Acquired Connection [jdbc:oracle:thin:system/system@localhost:1521/XE, UserName=SYSTEM, Oracle JDBC driver] for JDBC transaction
DEBUG - Switching JDBC Connection [jdbc:oracle:thin:system/system@localhost:1521/XE, UserName=SYSTEM, Oracle JDBC driver] to manual commit
DEBUG - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'sessionFactory'
DEBUG - Initiating transaction rollback
DEBUG - Rolling back JDBC transaction on Connection [jdbc:oracle:thin:system/system@localhost:1521/XE, UserName=SYSTEM, Oracle JDBC driver]
DEBUG - Releasing JDBC Connection [jdbc:oracle:thin:system/system@localhost:1521/XE, UserName=SYSTEM, Oracle JDBC driver] after transaction
DEBUG - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
DEBUG - Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'error'
DEBUG - Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name 'error'; URL [/WEB-INF/jsps/error.jsp]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
DEBUG - Added model object 'userBean' of type [com.sga.app.beans.UserBean] to request in view with name 'error'
DEBUG - Added model object 'org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.userBean' of type [org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult] to request in view with name 'error'
DEBUG - Added model object 'displayStatsDAO' of type [com.sga.app.dao.DisplayStatsDAO] to request in view with name 'error'
DEBUG - Added model object 'org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.displayStatsDAO' of type [org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult] to request in view with name 'error'
DEBUG - Added model object 'username' of type [java.lang.String] to request in view with name 'error'
DEBUG - Forwarding to resource [/WEB-INF/jsps/error.jsp] in InternalResourceView 'error'
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sga.app.dao.DisplayStatsDAO.getForename(DisplayStatsDAO.java:66)
    at com.sga.app.dao.DisplayStatsDAO$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$52d44a3e.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
```

And my DAO:

```
package com.sga.app.dao;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.sga.app.beans.UserBean;
import com.sga.app.hibernate.HibernateUtil;

@Component("displayStatsDAO")
@Repository
@Transactional
@Configuration
public class DisplayStatsDAO extends HttpServlet implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public static final String TEST = "testing";
public String string = TEST;
public String example = "example String";
public String forename;
public Session session;
private HibernateUtil hibernateUtil;

@Bean
public DisplayStatsDAO displayStatsDAO() {
    return new DisplayStatsDAO();
}

public DisplayStatsDAO() {

}

@Transactional
public String getForename() {
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    ArrayList result = new ArrayList();
    String returnValue = "";
    Session session = hibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    if (session == null) {
        System.out.println("NULL SESSION");
    } else {
        try {
            session.beginTransaction();
            Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder
                    .getContext().getAuthentication();
            String userLoggedIn = authentication.getName();
            System.out.println("SESSION IS ACTIVE");
            System.out.println(userLoggedIn);
            Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(UserBean.class);
            criteria.add(Restrictions.like("username", userLoggedIn));
            List<UserBean> user = (List<UserBean>) criteria.list();
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            for (UserBean userDetails : user) {
                result.add(userDetails.getForename());
                returnValue = userDetails.getForename().toString();
            }
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Return value is " + returnValue);
    }
    return returnValue;
}

public Session getSession() {
    return session;
}

public void setSession(Session session) {
    this.session = session;
}

public String getLoggedInUserName() {
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
            .getAuthentication();
    String userLoggedIn = authentication.getName();
    return userLoggedIn;
}

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    req.getRequestDispatcher("userstats.jsp").forward(req, resp);
}
}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
        oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    </property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
        jdbc:oracle:thin:system/system@localhost:1521/XE
    </property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">system</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
    <!-- Oracle dialect declaration -->
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">
        org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
    </property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <mapping resource="com/sga/app/xml/sga.hbm.xml"></mapping>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

HibernateUtil.java:

```
package com.sga.app.hibernate;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder;

public class HibernateUtil {

private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

public HibernateUtil() {
    sessionFactory = createSessionFactory();
}

public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return HibernateUtil.sessionFactory;
}

private static SessionFactory createSessionFactory() {

    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
    serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
            configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
    sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    return sessionFactory;
}
}
```

Pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0  
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>SgaWebApp</groupId>
<artifactId>SgaWebApp</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

app.hbm.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD   
3.0//EN""http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.sga.app.beans.UserBean" table="USERS">
    <id name="username" type="varchar">
        <column name="USERNAME"></column>
    </id>
    <property name="roundScore" type="int">
        <column name="ROUNDSCORE"></column>
    </property>
    <property name="fairways_hit" type="int">
        <column name="FAIRWAYS_HIT"></column>
    </property>
    <property name="gir" type="int">
        <column name="GIR"></column>
    </property>
    <property name="sand_saves" type="int">
        <column name="SAND_SAVES"></column>
    </property>
    <property name="putts" type="int">
        <column name="PUTTS"></column>
    </property>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

userstats.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sql" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sf" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/css/main.css"
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<title>SGA-user stats</title>
</head>
<body>
</div>
<br />
<!-- Logout option -->
<div id="logoutOptionDiv" align="right">
    <a id="logoutOption" style="color: blue;"
        href='<c:url value="/j_spring_security_logout"></c:url>'>Logout</a>
</div>
<br />
<h2 class="displayStatsLeaderboardHeader">Your stats</h2>
<table class="displayStatsTable" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Username</td>
        <td>Forename</td>
        <td>Surname</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="displayStatsTableData">${stats}</td>
        <td class="displayStatsTableData">${stats.string}</td>
        <td class="displayStatsTableData">${stats.example}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The null-pointer exception was eradicated when I changed the line:

```
Session session = hibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
```

to:

```
session = HibernateUtil.createSessionFactory().openSession();
```

I thought the problem was that I was originally attempting to get a session that was currently closed but I'd have expected to receive the 'session is closed!' message that I've seen previously? Anyway the null-pointer exception has been resolved.

(the code within the createSessionFactory() method in HibernateUtil was not changed)

Answer (score 2):

Your hibernateUtil field is null. In fact, why did you introduce an instance field for that?  Nothing is injected into it and you call a instance method on this null field.  Make the method static as:

```
public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
   return sessionFactory;
}
```

and then :

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
```

Comment: I have been trying numerous different things and I see why it would be null  by creating the instance Object. Have tried as you suggested however and still get same null-pointer at same line of code

Comment: Replace the constructor in HibernateUtil with a static initializer.

Comment: doesn't the debugger tell you anything on where is the null inside HibernateUtil then?

Comment: well I am using several logger.info() to debug in the console and there is nothing displayed from within the HibernateUtil class the last debug.info() before the exception occurs is directly before the fateful Session session - HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();

Answer (score 0):

**Try This :-** 
**Replace your** `HibernateUtil` **class with this one:-**

`import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;`

```
public class HibernateUtil {
private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;
static {
        try {
           sessionFactory = new   AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory(); 
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
          System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }
public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

**and you should also try**

`SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();`

`Session session = sessionfactory.openSession();`

instead of

`Session session = hibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();`

I hope it will work,.

**Updated**

```
@Autowired
private HibernateUtil hibernateUtil;
```

Comment: Thanks for the input but same null-pointer exception persists

Comment: I think you are missing something in your DAO code.
I can see you are using 

`private HibernateUtil hibernatUtil;`

so you should try `@Autowired` annotation on it.

Comment: `@Autowired`

`private HibernateUtil hibernateUtil;`